# Possible to yum install mysql without root access?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I need to set up a mysql client on CentOS, and usually do this with:

```
[pd@l01 ~]$ yum install mysql
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

However, I don't have root and I cannot sudo. is it possible for me to install `mysql` for the local user only (without sudo/root) or is this something where I need additional permission/access in order to do anything?

For reference:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
$ yum --version
3.4.3
Installed: rpm-4.11.3-43.el7.x86_64 at 2020-06-29 20:50
Built    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org> at 2020-04-01 
...
```

Comment: You need to contact your system administrator. We don't do end user support here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know, I was wondering if I could install something local-to-the-user-without-root with yum but i suppose not.

Comment: If you're installing globally then you have to have root access unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry you need to to be root. That will also install the mysql server